# MySQL to JSON results in empty Google visualisation chart

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm using the following code to create a JSON string from data extracted from a database:

```
//Build table
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label'=>'DateTime', 'type'=>'datetime'),
    array('label'=>'Temperature','type'=>'number')
);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($table,$row);
}
echo json_encode($table);
```

The 'validated' JSON output is:

```
{
"0": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 16:32:00",
    "temp": "19.062"
},
"1": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 16:40:00",
    "temp": "19.062"
},
"2": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 16:47:00",
    "temp": "19.062"
},
"3": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 17:00:00",
    "temp": "19.062"
},
"4": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 18:00:00",
    "temp": "19.062"
},
"5": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 18:26:00",
    "temp": "19"
},
"6": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 19:00:00",
    "temp": "19.062"
},
"7": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 20:00:00",
    "temp": "19"
},
"8": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 21:00:00",
    "temp": "19"
},
"9": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 22:00:00",
    "temp": "18.937"
},
"10": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-21 23:00:00",
    "temp": "18.875"
},
"11": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 00:00:00",
    "temp": "18.875"
},
"12": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 01:00:00",
    "temp": "18.812"
},
"13": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 02:00:00",
    "temp": "18.812"
},
"14": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 03:00:00",
    "temp": "18.75"
},
"15": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 04:00:00",
    "temp": "18.687"
},
"16": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 05:00:00",
    "temp": "18.687"
},
"17": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 06:00:00",
    "temp": "18.687"
},
"18": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 07:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"19": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 08:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"20": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 09:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"21": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 10:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"22": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 11:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"23": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 12:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"24": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 13:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"25": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 14:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"26": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 15:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"27": {
    "datetime": "2015-08-22 16:00:00",
    "temp": "18.625"
},
"cols": [
    {
        "label": "DateTime",
        "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
        "label": "Temperature",
        "type": "number"
    }
]
}
```

When I try to plot this data in a Google Visualisation LineChart, the chart is empty. I'm using the following for the page on which the chart should be plotted:

```
function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

The page shows the chart but there is no data plotted.

A typical data structure for the Google Visualisation API would be:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"DateTime","pattern":"","type":"datetime"},
        {"id":"","label":"Temperature","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"2015-08-18 13:00:00","f":null},{"v":21,"f":null}]},-
        {"c":[{"v":"2015-08-18 14:00:00","f":null},{"v":20,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2015-08-18 15:00:00","f":null},{"v":20.2,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2015-08-18 16:00:00","f":null},{"v":20.3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2015-08-18 17:00:00","f":null},{"v":20.5,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

This is my first time using these methods so I'm probably missing something really obvious. Any help would be appreciated though.

Comment: What do you want the json structure to look like, please show a small sample, edit your question to show this, dont add a comment

Comment: Edited to clarify expected outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `datetime`-value can't be provided via a string like e.g. a mysql-timestamp, the API requires a JS-Date-object.

Such an object may not be transported via JSON, but the API supports a particular string-format(see: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)

e.g. the Mysql-Date:

```
 2015-08-21 19:00:00
```

must become the string

```
Date(2015,7,21,19,0,0,0)
```

(note that JS starts counting the months with 0, so e.g. August is `7` not `8`)

You may build the string directly in your SELECT-statement.

Other issues:

- you should use the mysqli-functions instead of mysql(they are deprecated/outdated)
- you should not run `$.ajax` synchronously
- you didn't populate a rows-array with the columns

Try it like this:

### data.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
header('Content-Type:application/json');

//use your custom data
$dbhost   ='localhost';
$dbuser   ='username';
$dbpass   ='password';
$dbname   ='db-name';
$dbtable  ='table-name';


//db-connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//prepare the datatable
$table = array('cols'=>array(
                              array('label' => 'DateTime', 
                                    'type'  => 'datetime'),
                              array('label' => 'Temperature',
                                    'type'  => 'number')),
                'rows'=>array()
);


//build the query
$sql="SELECT 
              CONCAT(
                     'Date(',
                     YEAR(datetime),
                     ',',
                     Month(datetime)-1,
                     DATE_FORMAT(datetime,',%e,%k,%i,'),
                     '0)'
                    ) 
                        as `datetime`,
                            `temp` 
              FROM `{$dbtable}`";

//run the query  
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //populate the rows-array
        $table['rows'][]=array('c'=>array(
                                            array('v'=>$row['datetime']),
                                            array('v'=>$row['temp'])
                                         )
                              );
    }
    $result->close();
}
ob_end_clean();
die(json_encode($table));
?>
```

### HTML-File:

```
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="height:300px;"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
   $.getJSON('data.php',function(data){

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

      var chart = new google.visualization
                     .LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, {});
   });   
}
/*]]>*/
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Molle. Thank you so much. Not only does this work perfectly, but I've learned a huge amount. You've given me some really good pointers to address the things I didn't that I didn't know! Thanks again.