# PHP mysql json Google charts

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I am working on a project where I am making use of the Google Charting API and I want to populate the chart using json with php mysql.

```
<?php 

$sql = $db->query("SELECT  COUNT(depots_id) AS count FROM inputs WHERE etat_input ='Valider'");


$results = array();
while ($var = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $results[] = $var;

}                   

$pie_chart_data = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $pie_chart_data[] = array((int)$result['count']);
}
$pie_chart_data = json_encode($pie_chart_data);
?>
```

And the code javascript to building the chart :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number','depots_id');
        data.addRows({$pie_chart_data});

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>




 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>


            </div>
```

but it shows me no results.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158107/mysql-to-json-results-in-empty-google-visualisation-chart?rq=1), and may help you identify the issue.

If this still doesn't help, could you confirm that your PHP correctly outputs the JSON as expected (and even post an example of the output)?